# How to prevent application.properties property inheritence

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties-file

Suppose I have an `src/main/ressources/application.properties` containing the following (exemplary) entry:

```
server.ssl.trust-store=/config/app.jks
```

and multiple application.properties for multiple enviroments

```
/config
|---/prod
|   |---/application.properties // overrides "server.ssl.trust-store"
|---/int
    |---/application.properties
/src
|---/main
    |---/resources
        |---/application.properties // contains entry "server.ssl.trust-store"
```

Both application.properties in `/config` directory inherits from the src/main/resources/application.properties. In /config/prod/application.properties we want to override the entry. This all works as expected.

Now, my question is: is it possible to inhibit the inheritance of properties?
I tried overwriting it with an empty value, but that didn't worked and was differently interpreted as not setting it at all.

**Note:** For this particular case I know of the existence of `server.ssl.enabled=false` ([source](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.server.server.ssl.enabled)).

Comment: commenting-out (or removing or filtering) the property `server.ssl.trust-store` (in config/prod) isn't an option?

Comment: Commenting out is not an option, because it is used in most of the other environments. Filtering how?

Comment: if this `config/` directory is copied to a production deployment, it could be perhaps filtered by a `sed` script to exclude some properties

Comment: The problem is the copy of `src/main/ressources/application.properties` in midst of compiling, not the `/config` directory.

Comment: but, if i understood correctly, you want to prevent a property from `config` to override a property from classpath properties (`/src/main/resources`)

Comment: It's the other way around. If a property in `/config/*/application.properties` **IS NOT** present, it will be inherited from `src/main/ressources/application.properties`. And this is what I want to prohibit in some cases. My usecase is that I have a reasonable default value set, but it doesn't hold for 3 out of 27 environments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create a new spring profile, for example, `ssl`, and add the ssl configurations there

```
# in application-ssl.properties
server.ssl.trust-store=/config/app.jks
```

You can then enable these configurations in your apps on demand by "importing" the ssl profile.

```
# in application-prod.properties
spring.profiles.include=ssl
```

You would leave out this statements where you wouldn't want to have that value present.

Another way is to directly configure conditional properties in the `application.properties`

```
# in common application.properties
spring.myproperty=44 # ... etc, normal app properties
---
spring.config.activate.on-profile=ssl # These configs apply to the ssl profile
server.ssl.trust-store=/config/app.jks
```

Comment: By now, this seems to be the best answer. They really closed the gate to modifying application.properties after starting the application.